# How to take a range of elements from JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, rdd, java-pair-rdd

I am trying to get data from HBase using Spark.

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> javaPairRdd = 
sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, 
TableInputFormat.class,ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
```

But I need to get elements from a range. ex: 1000th record to 2000th record.